# SQL table with extra data broke SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, customer and email that are filled via web page. The join statement joins customer_id on email_id and the select statement joins customer_id on email_id (there is more on each table but these are the rows I'm concerned with). Somehow an extra email got submitted so when the SELECT query fires everyone's email is moved up one person. I need to add a proper foreign key constraint to the email table, but since the data is already off I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Example:

```
customer_name customer_id             email email_id
-------------------------             ---------------    
s                 1                      s      1
t                 2                      t      2
u                 3                      t      3
v                 4                      u      4
w                 5                      v      5
```

Comment: You would add the foreign key, truncate the email table and reenter the data from scratch. You might manually do that if names and email is giving an idea about which one belongs to which just by filling in the new column.

Comment: @scsimon yes there is currently no foreign key between the two, the select statement just references them by ID. SELECT * FROM customer JOIN customer_id=email_id, I need to figure out a way to line up the ID lines before adding a foreign key.

Comment: Nope, you would add the new column first, fill it with correct values and make that the foreign key. There is nothing like "line up".

Comment: @CetinBasoz So if I am understanding correctly, create a foreign key column for the customer_id in the email table, put the customer id in that correspond correctly, then just set that as my foreign key and reference that?

Comment: Yes, that would be the easiest fix (provided you know which email belongs to which person).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just off by 1 as in your sample then you can do like this:

```
alter table emails add customer_id int not null default 0;

update emails set customer_id = email_id;
update emails set customer_id = customer_id-1 where email_id > 2;


alter table emails add constraint custEmail  
  foreign key (Customer_id)
  references customers(customer_id);

select *
from customers
left join emails on customers.customer_id = emails.customer_id;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2266f72af38523f2d17f14cf9d4676a7)

Answer (score 0):

So a customer can only have a single email in your current case. It doesn't make sense that everyone's email is moved up one person. This means that you don't have a foreign key relationship at all. It seems like this is the relation you are going for:

```
alter table email 
add constraint customer_fx foreign key (email_id) references customer (customer_id)
```

This would relate the two tables and bind the customer to all the emails they could have (which you could restrict) but since your data is already jacked up, you'd have to fix that before you applied the constraint.

Comment: Why would a customer have a single email? If it were the case, what is the need for a separate table?

Comment: that part of my answer was regarding their current layout. I’ll edit.

Comment: That is the problem, current layout is faulty from the start. Person 2 (name t) has 2 emails already as I see it.

Comment: @CetinBasoz It is what I came into, not sure why it is separate and not just added on to the customer table as is. I could make a new column on the customer table and transfer everything but I am trying to avoid manually entering all the emails again past where the double entry occurred.

Comment: It it was the only problem he could simply add a new column, fill it with current email_id and then update the ones where break occurs to be +1. Then alter to make it a foreign key.

Comment: I did t correlate the email field with the name of the customer @CetinBasoz since the ID is different

Comment: OK I just added an answer based on that assumption.